# Is there a way to automatically deploy nuget packages in Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: nuget, nuget-package, visual-studio-2017

I'd like to know if there is a way to automatically deploy NuGet package.

I tried many extensions but not working for VS 2017.

I do know that there is a packager as new VS 2017 feature. But there is no package tab in my project (.NET Library) properties.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the integrated package management for .NET Framework Libraries (not .NET Standard or .NET Core), you can create a .NET Standard Library and edit the csproj file by replacing

```
<TargetFramework>netstandard1.4</TargetFramework>
```

with

```
<TargetFramework>net461</TargetFramework>
```

There is no built-in template yet for this library type and some designers (win forms, xaml, ..) will not be available but this unlocks all integrated packaging features.